# problemas para imprimir um numero double

Tags: java, matemática

Estou com problemas para imprimir um numero double, 
por exemplo eu crio uma variavel do tipo double, 
e este recebe o um divisao 1/3, teria que mostra 0.3,
o que eu tenho que fazer para imprimir 0.3???

```
public class MeuTeste{ 

public static void main(String [] a){ 
         double x=1;  
         double y=3;  
         System.out.println(x/y); 
    } 
} 
//0.3333333333333333
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a classe BigDecimal.

```
double variavel = 0.3333333333333333;
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(variavel);  
bd = bd.setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);  
System.out.println(bd.toString());
```

Comment: Obrigado isso funcionou pra mim.

Comment: você está com o Lync aberto?

Answer (score 6):

Mais uma maneira de formatar o valor da saída:

```
double x=1;  
double y=3;
double resultado = x/y;
System.out.format("%10.1f%n", resultado);
```

Answer (score 2):

Se quiser apenas truncar o valor para uma casa decimal, pode fazer assim:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
System.out.println(df.format(x/y));
```