# Formatar double em Java

Tags: java, formatação

Tenho o seguinte valor `1234.0000`.  Gostaria de formatar para a seguinte saída: `1.234,00`. Pode haver casos que vou usar também `1.234,0`, mas acredito que fazendo para o primeiro caso os demais são semelhantes.

Comment: Alguma coisa me diz que há algumas duplicatas desta pergunta já respondidas.

Comment: Encontrei apenas em c#

Comment: @MuriloFechio olhe se aqui pode te ajudar.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6691/problemas-para-imprimir-um-numero-double/6697#6697

Comment: Não dá @Marconi, porque não coloca o . no separador das milhares

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47102/101. Se ninguém achar um dup, eu posso responder mas queria achar antes de arriscar. Esta é dup? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16276/101

Comment: @bigown, testei as 3 respostas da pergunta citada pelo @Marconi para o valor `1234.000` que falei. Os resultados que obtive foram : `1234.0, 1234.0, 1234`, que não é o meu resultado esperado.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pode usar o DecimalFormat:

```
double d = 1243123.1;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

Saída:

> 1.243.123,10

Entretanto o DecimalFormat usa as propriedades do seu sistema operacional para definir o formato de saída, por exemplo, no Brasil usamos `,` para separar o número inteiro dos decimais, já nos EUA a `,` serve para separar os milhares. No meu SO a saída foi conforme mostrei acima, mas dependendo do SO pode sair um pouco diferente.

Se você não quiser permitir essas variações de SO, pode usar a classe Locale para localizar sua saída, e pode inclusive já adicionar a moeda à saída caso esteja trabalhando com dinheiro.

Exemplo:

```
double d = 1243123.1;

Locale localeBR = new Locale( "pt", "BR" );  
NumberFormat dinheiroBR = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(localeBR);  
System.out.println(dinheiroBR.format(d));

Locale localePT = new Locale( "pt", "PT" );  
NumberFormat dinheiroPT = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(localePT);  
System.out.println(dinheiroPT.format(d));

NumberFormat numeroBR = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(localeBR);
numeroBR.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
numeroBR.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
System.out.println(numeroBR.format(d));

Locale localeUS = new Locale( "en", "US" );  
NumberFormat numeroUS = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(localeUS);
numeroUS.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
numeroUS.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
System.out.println(numeroUS.format(d));
```

Saída:

> R$ 1.243.123,10
>   1.243.123,10 €
>   1.243.123,10
>   1,243,123.10

Comment: meu resultado aqui foi 1,243,123.10

Comment: @MuriloFechio hum, deve ser dependente do SO, e o seu provavelmente está no padrão US. Você queria no padrão que eu pus na resposta, correto?

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi definindo caracteres para separação das casas decimais e dos grupos:

```
    double d = 11356982.10000;

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();

    //define o caractere separador das casas decimais
    dfs.setDecimalSeparator(',');
    //define o caractere separador dos grupos das milhares
    dfs.setGroupingSeparator('.');
    //seta o formatador de simbolos ao formatador do decimal
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);

    String total = df.format(d);
```

Para o valor `11356982.10000` resultado `11.356.982,10`

Comment: Se resolveu marque a resposta correta para os futuros visitantes deste tópico.
A resposta do @Math ajudou, então creio que a resposta correta seria a dele.