# Como restringir o valor da variável com apenas duas casas decimais?

Tags: java

Quero o r com apenas duas casas decimais.

```
double r = Math.abs ((aux5 - ((aux1*aux2)/previsoes.length))/ (Math.sqrt(Math.abs((aux3 - ((aux1 * aux1) / previsoes.length)) * (aux4 - ((aux2 * aux2) / previsoes.length))))));
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Formatar double em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55720/formatar-double-em-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar esses dois métodos que deixam os valores truncados

Se você quer que o resultado for um double:

```
public static double truncate(double value) {
    return Math.round(value * 100) / 100d;
}
```

Se você quer um String:

```
public static String truncate(double value) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    return df.format(value);
}
```

Agora é só chamar o método passando como atributo o valor de `r`, que ele será transformado para um valor com apenas duas casas depois da virgula

Comment: Obrigado! Tudo certo!