# como deixar o resultado 93,1

Tags: java, float

Ao rodar o seguinte código:

```
package Aula_4;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercício_3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        float n1,n2,n3,n4;

        System.out.println("Digite a largura da parede");
        n1 = entrada.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Digite o comprimento da parede");
        n2 = entrada.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Sua parede tem " +n1*n2+ "m²");
        System.out.println("Agora digite a largura do tijolo");
        n3 = entrada.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Digite o Comprimento do tijolo");
        n4 = entrada.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Para esta parede você irá precisar de aproximadamente " +(n1*n2*100) / (n3*n4*100));
```

O Resultado apresentado é 93.13502, como arredondar para 93,1?

Comment: Não entendo por que alguém vai pra aula (no caso, Aula 4 :) e não pergunta pro professor.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Formatar double em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55720/formatar-double-em-java)

Answer (score 3):

Uma solução é utilizar *String.format*:

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
System.out.println(String.format("Para esta parede você irá precisar de aproximadamente :%.1f",(n1*n2*100) / (n3*n4*100)));
```

Nesse caso, o '%.1f' define que apresentará apenas uma casa decimal de sua variável float, você pode ler mais sobre o String.format na [documentação oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).
Repare que, para alterar o separador de "," para "." temos que definir uma nova Localidade com *Locale.setDefault*.

Outra solucão seria utilizar o *[DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)*:

```
float resultado=(n1*n2*100) / (n3*n4*100);
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###,###.0");
System.out.println(format.format(resultado));
```

Para utilizar o DecimalFormat é necessário adicionar:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
```

Vale lembrar que, como explicado pelo [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) o DecimalFormat também é afetado pelo locale, vale conferir o exemplo criado pelo próprio: https://ideone.com/nwrwjX .

Comment: Ainda não vai tudo, pois o resultado que será impresso será `93.1`, e ele está pedindo  `93,1`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Acho que isso depende do locale default da JVM: https://ideone.com/xhN1gq

Comment: @hkotsubo, era justamente isso que eu estava esperando (também) na resposta, visto que o exemplo fornecido pelo AP é usando `.` para separador de milhar (ou seja, provavelmente locale US).

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Outra alternativa é usar `Decimalformat`, mas na verdade eu tenho quase certeza que a pergunta é duplicada, só não achei uma boa pra indicar...

Comment: Como na questão ele escreveu "arredondar", pensei que a formatação do separador não fosse relevante.

Comment: @NetoCosta, pode ser _nitpicking_ da minha parte, mas ele reclama que o resultado é `93.13502` mas desejaria `93,1`. Ou seja, exceto se for um erro de digitação, foi intencional reclamar do separador de decimal

Comment: Vou editar a resposta!

Comment: Só um detalhe, `DecimalFormat` também é afetado pelo `Locale` default da JVM, então o ideal é criar um que use o locale específico: https://ideone.com/nwrwjX

Answer (score 2):

Apenas um adendo. Caso o objetivo seja apenas imprimir na tela, o String.format é o ideal, mas, caso queira armazenar o número em uma váriável, use

```java
Math.round((n1*n2*100) / (n3*n4*100)*10)/10;
```

Lembrando que é necessário importar o pacote java.util.math